# Perform SELECT on both tables before JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join, inner-join

I do not have too much experience using JOIN and not really an expert in MySQL.

What I want to do is a SELECT on both tables before doing a JOIN. For that I am trying to use parenthesis but the syntax is not correct.

For example, without doing SELECT before JOIN:

```
DELETE tbA.* FROM tbA
INNER JOIN tbB
ON tbA.id_tbB = tbB.id_tbB
WHERE tbB.dateCol<'2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

This works, but takes too much time. What I am trying to do, with no success, is something like:

```
DELETE tbA.* FROM (SELECT * FROM tbA WHERE tbA.id_tbB<=id_max)
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbB WHERE tbB.id_tbB<=id_max)
ON tbA.id_tbB = tbB.id_tbB
WHERE tbB.date<'2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

I tried to keep it synthesized to the basic question... if someone thinks that I should provide more information (what am I trying to do, indexes, foreign keys,...) I would be happy to do so, but basically I just want to know how to do a SELECT on both tables before INNER JOIN.

I want to do this cause my tables have huge amount of records (Table A ~ 100 millions, Table B ~ 40000). Doing a select before will reduce the amount of records to a 10% on both tables and hopefully significantly reduce the INNER JOIN, reducing the overall query.

Can anyone please point me out the error? Thanks!

Comment: What about moving the where clause to the join itself?  I'm not sure if the execution plan is doing the join (large cartesean) and then filtering or filtering is occuring before the join... such as  `DELETE tbA.* FROM tbA
INNER JOIN tbB
ON tbA.id_tbB = tbB.id_tbB
and tbB.dateCol<'2014-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
In your suggestion however, I am not seeing the condition (tbB.id_tbB<=id_max) which would reduce the data to 10%. Wouldn't this be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the actual answer (or at least one of them) to the question:

How to perform a SELECT on both tables before JOIN?

Is by using virtual tables... something like:

```
SELECT tbA_filter.* FROM (SELECT tbA.* FROM tbA WHERE tbA.id_tbB<=id_max) AS tbA_filter 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbB WHERE tbB.id_tbB<=id_max AND tbB.date<'2014-01-01 00:00:00') AS tbB_filter
ON tbA_filter.id_tbB = tbB_filter.id_tbB
WHERE tbA_filter.id_tbB<=id_max
```

However, if it is a DELETE action (as in my example) it would not be possible, since it is of no use to delete things on a virtual table (since it is a virtual table, not really the original).

Important to consider too that the virtual tables have no indexes... so it may not be smart to try to do a JOIN using two tables that have no indexes cause it will take forever (especially on tables with incredible huge amount of rows).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DELETE FROM tbA WHERE (select tbB.date from tbB where tbA.id_tbB = tbB.id_tbB) > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
```

OR an alternate

```
DELETE FROM tbA WHERE tbA.id_tdB IN (
     select tbB.id_tbB from tbB where tbB.date > '2014-01-01 00:00:00'
)
```

I would assume this last one is the fastest provided you have an index or foreign key on id_tdB in tbA.

Comment: My guess is that

select tbB.date from tbB where tbA.id_tbB = tbB.id_tbB

will be executed first right? In such a case, the WHERE clause is doing reference to tbA... wouldn't this fail?

Comment: I don't think either of these will fail provided I did not make a syntax error :)

Comment: Yes, id_tbB in tbA is actually a foreignkey pointing to tbB.id_tbB.

I will try and let you know (I am waiting for the last experiment to finish, and then I need to re-import the whole database and try again).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @beiller, this is what I got. The first one complaints about syntax. The second one works, and it takes 1100 seconds to finish. In comparison to not using any SELECT before JOIN (as I suggested in the question) it takes 869, so it actually took longer. Do not really know why, but it seems to me that in your suggestion we are doing a SELECT on tbB, and an IN clause instead of a JOIN. I think that, since tbA is not getting a SELECT clause applied before IN, the IN clause is taking each of the 100 million rows (original rows in tbA), probably that is why?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try just the """ select tbB.id_tbB from tbB where tbB.date > '2014-01-01 00:00:00' """ and see how long that takes. Is there an index on tbB.date? It seems to me you said tbB had less rows. Also your explanation doesn't make too much sense as the time difference is not significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should work, you're just missing a few important syntax elements. You can join on a SELECT, this is a called a derived table (virtual table). You do have to name the derived table so you can reference it. You can't DELETE from a derived table since it is virtual table, it only exists in memory. So you need to put a physical table in your selection.

Try something like this:

```
DELETE tbA FROM tbA 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbB WHERE tbB.id_tbB<=id_max AND tbB.date<'2014-01-01 00:00:00') AS tbB_filter
ON tbA.id_tbB = tbB_filter.id_tbB
WHERE tbA.id_tbB<=id_max
```

Derived tables can make things much quicker since it filters before hand and loads the selection into memory. Since it is a derived table, it has no indexes, so if your derived table gets too large it can actually slow things down. Select only the fields you need from a derived table to keep the memory footprint low. You can always do an additional join at the very end to get additional fields you need.

Comment: I have compared three different:

Comment: Thks for your suggestion @Brent. I have tried it, and it worked. It took 839 seconds. However, compared to NOT using any select at all (as suggested in the question text) it is not really a significant improvement (869 seconds). It seems to me that in your example, we are only doing a SELECT in tbB, but still trying to do the JOIN using the 100 million records in tbA. I do not know if the improvement comes from going from 40000 rows in tbB to 4000 rows in the virtual table tbB_filter. I think a greater improvement should come from doing the SELECT on tbA too. Let me know your thoughts and thxs

Comment: The tbA SELECT is very simple, I don't think separating it would do much. MySQL should be applying the WHERE filter on tbA before the JOIN. You could try moving the WHERE condition into the JOIN condition. Also only select id_tbB field for tbB_filter, not *. You should be testing performance with SELECT, not DELETE.